# How to write this function?

Tags: java, algorithm, queue

Write a method/function, called queues2stack, in pseudocode (or Java without using
specialised libraries) that receives two queues and creates a single stack that contains all the
information from each of the queues. Each of the two input queues contains a set of
integers and is ordered by having the integers in decreasing order (highest at the front of
the queue, lowest at the end). Your algorithm should always add the highest valued entries. The resulting stack will have the same number of entries as the sum of the number of entries in the two queues.

What I've written:

```
void queues2stack {
  while (!q1.empty & q2.empty) {    
    if (q1.pop () > q2.pop()) 
      s.push(q1.pop)
    else 
      s.push(q2.pop)
  }
    
  while (!q1.empty()) {
    s.push(q1.pop)
  }
  
  while !q2.empty() {
    s.push(q2.pop)
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is not working? What should happen that isn't?

Comment: You're missing a `!` on the `q2.empty` condition I think

Comment: What `pop` supposed to do? If it actually pops value from the top of the stack, you shouldn't do it twice when comparing and pushing to the resulting stack

Answer (score 0):

Use `peek()` to check the values without removing them.

```
void queues2stack {
  while (!q1.empty & q2.empty) {    
    if (q1.peek() > q2.peek()) 
      s.push(q1.pop())
    else 
      s.push(q2.pop())
  }
    
  while (!q1.empty()) {
    s.push(q1.pop)
  }
  
  while !q2.empty() {
    s.push(q2.pop)
  }
}
```